# Nginx docker container not resolving custom domain name

Tags: docker, nginx

I am new to nginx and trying to understand what is going on here.  I have a docker compose file that starts up a nginx container like so:

```
  proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: proxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Which copies my default.conf into the nginx container, which looks like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name localhost testthis;

    return 301 https://www.google.com$request_uri;
}
```

So if I run `curl -I http://localhost`, I see google.com as expected

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.21.6
Date: Fri, 25 Feb 2022 06:39:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.google.com/
```

But if I run `curl -I http://testthis`, I get this response:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: testthis
```

Why is this happening if the server names are on the same server block? Eventually I am wanting to set up a custom domain and subdomains to forward requests to specific localhost ports per app but not understanding how this works too well.

Answer (score 1):

`curl -I http://localhost` works because `localhost`, by default, resolves to an IP from your machine (127.0.0.1), not because it's listed in your nginx's `default.conf`. And Docker configures your machine to forward traffic on port 80 and 443 (the ones used for HTTP and HTTPS) to that container.

The `server_name` directive in nginx's configuration makes it recognize requests with that DNS in the request's `Host:` header. It does not advertise that as a name for your network.

For that to work, you need to make your computer recognize `testthis` as a name for your computer. On Linux, edit `/etc/hosts` and add this line:

```
127.0.0.1 testthis
```

On Windows, I don't know, but you can certainly search for "windows hosts file" and get a similar method.

Answer (score 0):

`curl --connect-to testthis:80:127.0.0.1:80 http://google.com` should do the trick